# DB2 LUW 9.X: Multirow insert in stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

what is the best way performancewise to insert multiple rows to a table from a stored procedure?

```
EXEC SQL
  INSERT INTO DSN8A10.ACT 
    (ACTNO, ACTKWD, ACTDESC)
    VALUES (:HVA1, :HVA2, :HVA3)
    FOR :NUM-ROWS ROWS
END-EXEC.
```

The above is apparently only available in z/os but not in luw. Is there any equivalent?

Comment: Insert rows from where?

Comment: Stored procedure's array parameter in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DB2 9.x" is a bit too broad of a specification. Beginning with DB2 9.7 you might use the [`UNNEST()` table function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0055064.html?lang=en), something like this:

```
insert into ACT (ACTNO, ACTKWD, ACTDESC) 
select ACTNO, ACTKWD, ACTDESC from unnest (V_ARR) as (ACTNO, ACTKWD, ACTDESC);
```

assuming `V_ARR` is an array of row type with "columns" `ACTNO`, `ACTKWD`, and `ACTDESC`.